# Karma clear screen before running tests

Tags: karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I use karma to run jasmine specs. Every time a file changes the tests are run. This is awesome but it would be even better if the previous test output would be removed from the terminal.

Is there a way to clear the terminal before tests are run in karma?

Comment: Never heard about this, but I would rephrase "Is there a way to clear the terminal *before* the `autoRun` processes tests again?".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue @Sylvain has created is still open, but there is a plugin [karma-clear-screen-reporter](https://github.com/arthurc/karma-clear-screen-reporter) which does the job. Internally it uses the magic:

```js
console.log('\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H');
```

Alternatively you can also place this at the top of your test runner code to clear the console yourself.

Answer (score 7):

It is not supported. I like this idea though. I created [issue #1004](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1004) to support this.

Answer (score 1):

## Context

My answer is the same as @bluenote10

The difference is that I made some improvements to the package he posted and published it on my github:

[Karma Clear Screen](https://github.com/wictorChaves/karma-clear-screen)

### Improvements

- Improvement in the initial message.
- Date of the update.
- In addition to `console.log('\u001b[2J\u001b[0;0H');` the spacing has been improved.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks.